# Apache httpd ssl reverse proxy

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, proxy

I have the following scenario:

- Web application (currently running in Eclipse)
- Apache httpd proxy
- 5 backend servers (tomcat) all listening on HTTPS

I have valid certificates for all backend servers and also have the cert chain imported in the keystore. Can anyone explain to me or give me a sample config for the proxy? I am getting different errors when trying to establish trust between the proxy and backend servers like (downstream server wanted client certificate but none are configured).